# How to keep the portfolio updated while working at design studios?

Tags: business, portfolio, work, contract

In my experience, when you work with branding agencies or design studios or organisation of such nature, you are kind of bound by law or contract not to disclose your work for a certain period of time which is understandable because the clients the studios work for may not be comfortable with it before they adopt the new design.
In such cases, how does a designer keep his portfolio updated? The next employer most certainly would like to see what the candidate did for the previous company or even to judge his skills, but the designer may not be able to disclose or publish the work.

Comment: +1 since im also want to know about this

Comment: *" .. may not be able to disclose or publish the work."* which means you can not use it in any portfolio, so there's no updating. Related, if not a duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115101/how-exactly-should-i-ask-my-employer-for-design-use-permission-on-paper

Comment: @Scott you misunderstood the question. I'm asking if you can't show what you did, then what do you show to the future employer ? I'm asking what, not how.

Comment: well.. what did you have in your portfolio to show this current employer?

Comment: @Scott Personal projects and project that I had permission to show from my previous employer. But think this scenario: if you work in a studio for 2-3 years and for that long period, you will have only personal projects. Is that good enough to land the next job? If it worked for junior designer level, doesn't mean it should work for higher experience level too. That's my thought though. I'm thinking it's completely logical for the next employer to ask "well show us what you did for past 2 years"